# Maven hangs while running test case Eclipselink & hsqldb

Tags: java, maven, eclipselink, hsqldb, perfectjpattern

Using `jps` and `jstack` I can get to the offending waiting thread but don't know how to troubleshoot it or what is causing it. See below the Maven dependencies and the `jstack` result and the waiting thread with `tid=0x000000000022c000`. Analysing further it seems an issue between Eclipselink and hsqldb for the chosen versions. I got this issue as result of upgrading those two libraries since it used to work perfectly for versions 2.0.1 and 1.8.0.10 of Eclipselink and hsqldb respectively.

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
  </dependency> 
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
   <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.9</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>                
</dependencies>
<repositories>
<repository>
   <id>EclipseLink</id>
   <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
</repository>
```

and the stacktrace is:

```
$ jstack 7552
2012-12-21 22:48:53
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.12-b01 mixed mode):

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000006a19000 nid=0x1e00 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000006a0a800 nid=0x2184 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000069f5000 nid=0x754 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000069f3800 nid=0x219c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000069a1800 nid=0x2198 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x000000000699f000 nid=0x2384 in Object.wait() [0x00000000075ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000007aef280e0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
        - locked <0x00000007aef280e0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000006990800 nid=0x21cc in Object.wait() [0x00000000074ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000007aef38070> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
        - locked <0x00000007aef38070> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=6 tid=0x000000000022c000 nid=0xbc0 waiting on condition [0x000000000220c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000007acd840a0> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:811)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:969)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1281)
        at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:207)
        at org.hsqldb.lib.CountUpDownLatch.await(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x00000007acd83f70> (a org.hsqldb.Session)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x00000007acdb2518> (a org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:938)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:537)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1800)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:648)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2681)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2634)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:420)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1149)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:852)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1108)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:2946)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1602)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1584)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeQuery(ServerSession.java:621)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1448)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1423)
        at org.perfectjpattern.jee.integration.dao.ReadQueryAdapter.getResultList(ReadQueryAdapter.java:79)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.perfectjpattern.core.structural.AbstractSurrogate.invoke(AbstractSurrogate.java:115)
        at $Proxy2.getResultList(Unknown Source)
        at org.perfectjpattern.jee.integration.dao.JpaBaseDao.findByNamedQuery(JpaBaseDao.java:158)
        at org.perfectjpattern.support.test.AbstractTestBaseReadOnlyDao.testFindByNamedQueryPositional(AbstractTestBaseReadOnlyDao.java:100)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
        at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It does indeed look like a hsqldb issue.** Following directions [from here](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27069722) the solution was to append the following to the connection-url `;hsqldb.tx=mvcc` whatever that means :/

Comment: MVCC means Multiversion Concurrency Control. It avoids locking whole database tables when a thread modifies a row. It allows other threads to read the whole table and to modify different rows, even before the first thread has committed.

Comment: This is also equivalent to SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL MVCC
More info: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sessions-chapt.html#snc_tx_tx_cc

Comment: Appending ;hsqldb.tx=mvcc to the connection url didn't help in my case. I use an in-memory database which reads a file based predefined db from the classpath (jdbc:hsqldb:res:<claspath-file>). Explicitely calling SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL MVCC in the test setup did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

For me this meant that I was using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto "update" as well as using raw connections to connect to the same HSQL in memory DB.  Separating the two into separate in-memory HSQL db's and it started working.  Current theory: maybe something is holding onto a session or transaction (esp. one that modifies a whole table) and not closing it? (unfortunately the mvcc fix mentioned didn't help in my case)

hsqldb version 2.3.4, hibernate 4.0.1.Final

my trace:

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fb636001000 nid=0x1303 waiting on condition [0x000000010a68c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007957cbd18> (a org.hsqldb.lib.CountUpDownLatch$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at org.hsqldb.lib.CountUpDownLatch.await(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000007957cbbe0> (a org.hsqldb.Session)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
```

also ran into it even more with hsqldb version 2.3.4, hibernate 4.1.12.Final

4.0.1.Final worked OK though weird.