# Deadlock on HSQL with two entity managers

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I have two entity managers (and this has to stay as it is). I am using in-memory database for unit tests. When I run the tests, I find the following issues.

As in this simple case:

```
  emFirst.createNativeQuery("select * from schema1.table").getResultList();

  emSecond.createNativeQuery("create table schema2.table (id int)").executeUpdate();
```

It gets stuck in a deadlock after upgrading HSQL from 2.3.2 to 2.3.4

In order to to make it work again i have to wrap each statement in transaction.

Do you know how can I make it work without using below?

```
    getTransaction().begin();
    emFirst.createNativeQuery("select * from schema1.table").getResultList();
    getTransaction().commit();

    getTransaction().begin();         
    emSecond.createNativeQuery("create table schema2.table (id int)").executeUpdate();
    getTransaction().commit();
```

I am using Hibernate 4.3.6

Here is a heap dump from deadlock:

```
> "main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7be0015000 nid=0x3b29 waiting
> on condition [0x00007f7be8584000]    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
> (parking)     at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>   - parking to wait for  <0x000000073635b3d0> (a org.hsqldb.lib.CountUpDownLatch$Sync)    at
> java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)     at
> java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
>   at org.hsqldb.lib.CountUpDownLatch.await(Unknown Source)    at
> org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)   at
> org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
>   - locked <0x000000073635b298> (a org.hsqldb.Session)    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)    at
> org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
>   - locked <0x00000007363a92f8> (a org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement)     at
> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:147)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:211)
>   at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1310)
>   at
> org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:389)
```

Comment: Possibly this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001558/maven-hangs-while-running-test-case-eclipselink-hsqldb

Answer (score 0):

Use an HSQLDB Server instead of an in-process database.

Comment: The database is used in unit tests. Hence it is supposed to be in-memory db. I will edit the original post

Comment: You can start a server with an in-memory database. The server could be started from your app. In that case the CREATE statement will wait for the emFirst to commit.

Comment: I see your point. But why does it wait? what has changed there since HSQL 2.3.2? Why would now commit for a readonly SELECT be needed on hibernate session level?

Comment: What has changed is HSQLDB 2.3.4 now waits for all transactions (including SELECT) to commit before executing CREATE TABLE or any other DDL statement. This may improve in next version.

Answer (score 0):

Probably switching to MVCC mode might work, see http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_db_operations.
Appending `;hsqldb.tx=mvcc` to the connection url didn't help in my case. I use an in-memory database which reads a file based predefined db from the classpath (jdbc:hsqldb:res:). Explicitly calling SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL MVCC in the test setup did the trick.